# How much that Query will occupy in TempDB - TSQL

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, tempdb

When I make a Insert Into statement it exists any way to predicte how much space that statement it will fill in TempDB?

Thanks

Comment: The only way to "predict" it would be to run a query to see how much data is in the rows. What are you really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I'm having troubles about size in TempDB and I want to verify each time that I run the statement if it's gonna return error because the size of TempDB or not

Comment: sounds like your problem isn't likely a single query but a tempdb size (disk allocation) problem.

Comment: Yes, I already ask for add more disk. But I am trying to add more best practices in my processes.  And I think that Know if the query statement will be very heavy to the TempDB... there exists any way?

Comment: NumberOfRows * SpaceReservedForEachRow = PredictedSpaceTheStatementWillConsume You may want to start at this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176029(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: You seem to be lacking any real details about what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob H :)

Answer (score 1):

This question can be answered in different ways.  I generally use different drives for Data, Log, and TempDB.  As a rule of thumb, I use 1/3 to 1/2 of the size of the data disk for both, the log disk and the TempDB disk.

Example:
Disk C:\   for OS           50 GB
Disk D:\   for SQL-Server   50 GB
Disk J:\   for Data        100 GB
Disk L:\   for Log          40 GB
Disk T:\   for TempDB       40 GB

For a development server I occasionally use only a C:\ and a D:\ drive.  In that case, if I have the same space requirements as above, Disk C:\ would still be 50 GB, but Disk D:\ is now the combine amount of 230 GB